# JDBC:SQLite stops events

Tags: java, linux, swing, netbeans

Environment:
Linux Mint 20.3
Kernel 5.4.0-109-generic
Cinnamon 5.2.7
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Project is a Apache Netbeans 13 project for built for JDK 11...also installed

My question has to do with events that occur during SQL queries. Specifically, add, update or delete - or drop index or create index.

These functions are extremely resource consuming and block GUI events.

How do I detect GUI events during database operations that consume time and resources?

Example:
I have a JFrame that performs an operation in my app that drops all indexes, clears a table and reads from a file, parses the text and creates database records to load into the database. All database operations are performed by a SQLiteProxy module in the app. Once started, the GUI does not respond to any mouse or keyboard events. This is only true for multiple record adds since single record adds are quite fast.

I would like to be able to abort the operation if necessary after the start.

So how do I do that?

So far I have looked at the events tutorial and threads documentation. Neither of which really addresses my problem.

If code is necessary, I can post my code to for you to analyse for this one operation. It is a large project.

Comment: You execute long-running SQL in a separate thread.  If you have an application model made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes, the SQL uses the application model and is completely independent of the GUI view.

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: As mentioned before "So far I have looked at the events tutorial and threads documentation. Neither of which really addresses my problem."

Comment: I have been doing a lot of research on this subject and it gets confusing. The results were basically split into two groups. 1) Make a separate thread for the JDBC database actions. And, 2) use SwingWorker to call the database functions and update the GUI when each call is done.

Comment: Specifically, I want to update a text field with the # of records written by the proxy ( a separate class). The read text/write db records loop is in a function of a dialog.

So is the SwingWorker part of the dialog and if so then does it contain the loop or is it called by the loop? Does the SwingWorker do the GUI updates (such as progressBar updates) or is that done somewhere else?